# What is the purpose of RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR?

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

I understand that `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` associates a message error which only has a meaning to the user. But can't the user just write a similar exception the following way?

```
DECLARE
e_negative EXCEPTION;


BEGIN
IF v_sid < 0 THEN
RAISE e_negative;
...

EXCEPTION
WHEN e_negative THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('An id cannot be negative');
```

Comment: you should edit your question and include more tags if you want your post to be seen by the right crowd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`raise_application_error` does more than print an error message to the console (like `dbms_output.put_line` does).

First, it's an actual error - it fails the statement, terminates the current block's execution, and propagates to outer blocks (similar to `throw` in Java or `raise` in Python).

Second, it actually returns this error regardless of the console. `dbms_output`'s messages may be turned off or ignored, depending on the client. Raising an application error allows you to return the details of the failure, regardless of the client.